# Auto Trigger 3rd Button with same classes

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-8

I have create a button via Javascript.

**JS Code:**

```
var print_via_pos_button = this.add_action_button({
     label: _t('Print via POS'),
     name: 'pos_print',
      click: function(){
        //functionalities
     }
});
```

**HTML Code:**

**NOTE**: The is dynamically created and i dont have access to change it.

```
        <div class="pos-actionbar">
            <ul class="pos-actionbar-button-list">
            <li class="button ">
            <div class="icon">
                <img src="/point_of_sale/static/src/img/icons/png48/printer.png">
                <div class="iconlabel">Print</div>
            </div>
        </li><li class="button ">
            <div class="icon">
                <img src="/point_of_sale/static/src/img/icons/png48/go-next.png">
                <div class="iconlabel">Next Order</div>
            </div>
        </li><li class="button ">
            <div class="label">
                Print via POS
            </div>
        </li></ul>
        </div>
```

**Output:**

[image]

The 3rd button in the row is Custom and i want to auto-tiggert it on screen initialize, but the problem is and the 3 buttons has the same classes, i think to add a id but `name` tag didnt add anything inline, so how can i trigger the button. Any solution?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: you can do : ```$('.name-of-class')[2]``` to select 3rd element of a class

Comment: hello, i tried `$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button ")[2].click(); 
   });` but it didnt work

Comment: you should do:  ```$(".button")[2].trigger('click');```

Comment: In case that doesnt work, setTimeout
``` setTimeout(function(){
$(".button")[2].trigger('click');
},2000)```